# Uninstalling the default US-Qwerty keyboard layout off Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-layout, dvorak, qwerty

Following [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/76629/international-dvorak-keyboard-doesn't-trigger-hot-keys) I'd like to try and completely remove the Qwerty layout.
However, the default tool that comes with Windows won't allow such change.
I wonder if there is a lower-level way to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open Control Panel then "Region and Language".

Next, go to the "Keyboards and Languages" Tab.

Simply click on any keyboard and as long as you have a secondary keyboard, you should see the option to remove.

[image]

Comment: Oh, I see you found this thread already.:)

Thanks! I forgot to select the Dvorak layout as the default for all input, and now I'm able to remove it.

Comment: I have done this (removed US-English), but for some reason, Windows still auto-switches back to it periodically, and it's available in the Language Bar?

Comment: @BenMosher This setting is per user, so maybe you are logged into Windows under a different account when that happens?

Answer (score 2):

The key issue is that the one you want to remove cannot be the current default.  Take note of the top group labeled: 'Default Input Language' and ensure that the one you want to remove is not the default.  Once you correct that, the remove is no longer grayed out.