# Remove permanently Dvorak from Windows

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, windows-registry, dvorak

I read this document: [Windows says Dvorak is the default keyboard layout, but all new windows use QWERTY](https://superuser.com/questions/266445/windows-says-dvorak-is-the-default-keyboard-layout-but-all-new-windows-use-qwer)

I found the corresponding key in registry for Dvorak.

The problem is when Windows restarts then Dvorak appears as default keyboard language and it is nasty.

It is possible, first, to hide it (using a registry value) from Keyboard language from Regional settings window?

It is safe to remove permanently the corresponding key from registry? Of course, I made a backup for it in case of emergency.

Comment: Can't you just delete the "United States-Dvorak" layout? You need to first select the "Us" keyboard and "Apply", after that you can click it and choose "Remove". (No need to dig in the registry)

Comment: No, I want to delete permanently this Dvorak, it is a pain for me ! Sometimes, I don't know the reason, windows make Dvorak default and when I press T characters, on screen appears O.

Comment: It is probably randomly changing you to Dvorak when you press **Ctrl** + **Shift**.  For some reason, Microsoft thought that would be a good default key combo for cycling through all the available keyboard layouts.  You can disable that in the Regional/Keyboard settings.

Answer (score 1):

Did you delete it already from your "Keyboard language from Regional settings"? Or is it still visible under the "Installed services"? See picture at the bottom.

If it's not under there (or you deleted it) and after a restart it comes back as an "Installed service" it indicates another problem.

If you delete it from "Installed services" it should not come back.

---

But if you really want to delete the keyboard via the registry you can.

**First** make **sure** the keyboard **is not** in the "Installed services". (See picture below)

Then, in `regedit.exe` goto the key
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Keyboard Layouts\00010409`

It should say `Layout Text = United States-Dvorak` on the right. You could delete the whole `00010409` key. (You can also rename the key to `dddd_00010409`. Windows doesn't recognize it again as keyboard layout.) No need to restart. You won't be able to add `United States-Dvorak` again.

BTW there is also a `00030409 United States-Dvorak for left hand` and
`0040409 United States-Dvorak for right hand` in my Windows version.

[image: Keyboard]

Comment: Just a reminder that you do have to change the Default Input Language section to be set to something other than Dvorak or it will not let you remove it from the lower list.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 8, you can add or remove Input Methods in Control Panel. To remove the Dvorak keyboard, follow these steps.

1. Open Control Panel and click on **Change input methods** under **Clock, Language, and Region**.

[image: Input Methods in Control Panel]

2. Click **Options** to edit the input methods for a language:

[image: Input Methods for a language]

3. To remove the Dvorak keyboard, click **Remove**, then **Save**.

[image: Remove Dvorak keyboard]